# Division operator in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, division

When I execute the following cypher:

```
CREATE (n:Person {name: 'Andy',sal:600/3, title: 'Developer'})
```

The salary value will equals 300.
But when execute the following:

```
CREATE (n:Person {name: 'Andy',sal:1/2, title: 'Developer'})
```

The salary value will equals 0.
What should I do to retrieve the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value appears to be integer, so an easy way to fix this is to use `toFloat`:

```
CREATE (n:Person {name: 'Andy', sal: toFloat(1)/2, title: 'Developer'})
WITH n
MATCH (n:Person)
RETURN n
```